# How to translate a php string using google translate or any other translation service?

Tags: php, google-translate, google-translation-api

I need to translate a part of my wordpress site content using google translate,
For example,

```
$text="translate this content"
```

to

```
$translated_text="traduci questo contenuto"
```

I do not need to find the browser language, etc,. Just direct translation I need.
Tried this, seems like it is deprecated. Got it from another question answered here.

```
 function translate($from_lan, $to_lan, $text){
 $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate? 
 v=1.0&q=' . urlencode($text) . '&langpair=' . $from_lan . '|' . $to_lan));
 $translated_text = $json->responseData->translatedText;
 return $translated_text;
 }
```

I don't mind paying for the google API, I need to know how to handle the translation in php code.

Comment: https://rapidapi.com/blog/lp/google-translate-api/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Alpha&utm_term=google%20translation%20api_e&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIqrvRvdXw7QIVSeDtCh2UjgI3EAAYASAAEgLWzPD_BwE

Answer (score 0):

google translate currently posts a "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" with a f.req like

```
[[["AVdN8","[\"je voudrais bien te voir demain\",\"fr\",\"nl\"]",null,"generic"]]]
```

For an example in posting with PHP, see [PHP post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Comment: am ok with using Google API by paying for it. I just need to know how to do that.

Comment: how to use the API or how to pay for it?  ;-)

Comment: How to use the API to translate a string?

Comment: You've studied https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs ?

Comment: Yes, went through it., But never in a place is mentioned how to use it to auto translate a sentence in php, with an example.

Comment: Perhaps not in PHP, but they show you what you need to post. Plenty of tutorials around showing how to post from PHP.

Comment: Added a link to my answer.